# Unable to open jar file on double click and in command prompt

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am using Windows 8.1pro 64bit-OS.
After I build my project in Netbeans IDE it was working good, but as I Clean & Build it and followed:-

> "To run this application from the command line without Ant, try: java
> -jar "C:\Users\ARSH-PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\arsh\dist\arsh.jar" jar: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)"

It was not running on double click as well as in command prompt.

Please give me solution to this. Thank You.

[SOLVED]

I just got solution to this problem. The thing which I was doing wrong was, I was not adding the code, java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { new add().setVisible(true); } }); to the main.java main class file while creating the jar file Clean & Build Project. Thus the jar file was not opening on double click as well as in command prompt.

Comment: to run it with double click it needs some extra effort, but what did it say in command prompt?

Comment: I just got solution to this problem.
The thing which I was doing wrong was, I was not adding the code,
 
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new add().setVisible(true);
            }
        }); 

to the main.java main class file while creating the jar file Clean & Build Project.
Thus the jar file was not opening on double click as well as in command prompt.
Thank You xerx593 for your help. 